# Sorting table with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting, tablesorter

How to sort table in php?

I have code like this

```
<th>$ATTT[0]</th>
        <td>".number_format($HA[0], 3, '.', ',')."</td>
        <td class='jumlah'>1</td>
        </tr>
        <th>$ATTT[1]</th>
        <td>".number_format($HA[1], 3, '.', ',')."</td>
        <td class='jumlah'>2</td>
```

I want to sort column 2, so when column 2 sorting column 1 will follow column 2

[image: my table]

Sorry for my English, I tried my best :D

Comment: Sort your `$HA` array and then iterate in HTML.

Comment: the easiest would be to do an `order by` on your query

Comment: i try create like this @SahilGulati
$HA;
rsort($HA);

$arrlength = count($HA);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $HA[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}

showing
0.61439523842828
0.38560476157172

how if i want to add $ATTT to that code, so ATT will follow HA

Comment: @Jazuly can you give me `json_encode($HA)` ?

Comment: how to get json code?

Answer (score 0):

In that case there are two options, use `order by` in your query so that you get the data in some order or use `JQUERY datatable plug-in` which have so many features like sorting, searching, pagination etc. It can be used like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

[Reference](https://datatables.net/)

[Demo](https://pandeyz.github.io/Jquery-datatable-client-side-demo-implementation/)

[How to implement](https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-datatable-client-side-demo-implementation/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: i try create like this @Mayank
$HA; rsort($HA); $arrlength = count($HA); for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) { echo $HA[$x]; echo "<br>"; } showing 0.61439523842828 0.38560476157172 how if i want to add $ATTT to that code, so ATT will follow HA

Comment: Jazuly: I am not getting you ?

Comment: can u give me example based my code, im not realy understand with php.

Comment: Or you want to implement it using php?

Comment: cant i implement based that my table? @Mayank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139350/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-jazuly).